# Why doesn't mongoid add my nested attributes on new()?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, nested-attributes

I can't seem to figure out why Mongoid won't set the nested attributes for a child object when I create a new parent.  I want to create a new Folio, add one child Feature, then push it on the Folios array on Profile.

I have a Profile, which embed many Folios, which embed many Features:

```
class Profile
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Updated

  #regular fields here; removed for brevity

  embeds_many :folios, class_name: "Folio"
end

class Folio
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Updated

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :features
  embedded_in :profile

  field :name
  field :desc
  field :order, type: Integer, default:0
  embeds_many :features

  attr_accessible :name, :desc, :order  
end

class Feature
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Updated

  embedded_in :folio
  belongs_to :project

  field :content_type, type: Integer  #ContentType
  field :content_id
  field :txt, type: String
  field :order, type: Integer, default:0

  attr_accessible :project_id, :content_type, :content_id, :txt, :order
end
```

Controller:

```
  def new
    @folio = Folio.new
    @folio.features.build
  end

  def create
    @folio = Folio.new(params[:folio])

    #@folio.features is still empty here.

    @profile.folios << @folio
    @profile.save
    render "create_or_update.js"
  end
```

In create, the param hash looks good:

```
{"folio"=>{"id"=>"new", "name"=>"new name", "desc"=>"new description", "features_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"project_id"=>"4ea0b68e291ebb44a100000a", "content_type"=>"1", "content_id"=>"4ea0b68e291ebb44a100000d", "txt"=>"note here"}}}, "commit"=>"Save", "action"=>"create", "controller"=>"folios"}
```

But @folio.features is still empty.

This worked fine with AR, if I remember. Strangely, there is no features_attributes=() method on Folio.  I thought that was required for the nested attributes to work?  What am I missing?

This is on Rails 3.1 with Mongoid 2.2.3.

Comment: did you manage to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried enabling **AutoSave** true for features in Folio document

```
class Folio
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps::Updated

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :features , :autosave => true
  embedded_in :profile
end
```

Comment: Worked.  According to the docs, that shouldn't be required for embedded docs.  I also had to add attr_accessible: features_attributes to Folio to get it to work.